# MVC3 Page - IsPostback like functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest

I call the same controller many times from _Layout.cshtml view. So in this controller, how can I discover at runtime if it's still same page that is rendering or if a brand new page request is being made?

In asp.net you can use ispostback to figure this out. How can you tell if a brand new request is being made for a page in MVC3?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no such think on MVC. You've actions that can handle POSTs, GETs or both. You can filter what each action can handle using `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` attributes.

On MVC, the closest you can get to `IsPostBack` is something like this within your action:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

Therefore,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateModel model) 
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") // <-- always true
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your post opened my mind to a new can of worms of being RESTFUL. My HttpRequest in this case will always be a GET. So with the [HttpGet] attribute, there is still no way of differentiating if we are at the beginning of the request or latering in the request. BUT I guess there is no such thing in MVC3 like you say.

Answer (score 3):

Might I also suggest you implement it as property in your controller base class like:

```
protected bool IsPostback 
{
    get { return Request.HttpMethod == "POST"; }
}
```

-Marc

Answer (score 0):

Actually are this way:

```
    if (Request.Method == "POST")
    {

    }
```