# How to detect postback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, postback

I need to fill the text  with current datetime only on a first page load using Javascript.
I mean that I'm looking for analog to Page.IsPostBack property in ASP.NET, but in JS.

I've found solutions, where I was adviced to use server-side code to detect postback and pass a variable to client-side. But I'm using MVC, and there is no property such as Page.IsPostBack...

Please, help me find the answer

Comment: There is not? You have `ViewBag` (for example) and `[HttpPost]`. Put them together: add `ViewBag.IsPostBack = true` in your method with `[HttpPost]` and you'll get that variable in your view. BTW Can't you fill that text box server side as you'd fill a form input?

Comment: There are no postbacks in MVC.  Can't you simply fill the text in a document ready?  I.e. when the page has loaded.  Or is there some other condition to be satisfied?

Comment: Adam, I guess, when user presses F5, the text in <input> will be refilled? It's unacceptable :(

Answer (score 1):

There's no such think on MVC. You've actions that can handle POSTs, GETs or both. You can filter what each action can handle using [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] attributes.

On MVC, the closest you can get to IsPostBack is something like this within your action:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

Therefore,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateModel model) 
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") // <-- always true
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

ref: [MVC3 Page - IsPostback like functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275384/mvc3-page-ispostback-like-functionality)

Comment: my action always uses GET methid, so I think your example won't work fine

Comment: you can't do that in javascript until you set value in variable from server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
      // ...
    }

    @if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
       @Html.Raw("myFunction();")
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{

   ViewBag.IsPostBack=true;

}
```

Then in your view

```
<script>
  var isPostBack=@ViewBag.IsPostBack;
</script>
```

Comment: and how can this help me to detect the first load of page?

Comment: @Andrew, The first load of page usually a `GET` request. Here i used `[HttpPost]` which can be called only when you make a post.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing here that you're working with MVC, there's no such "post back" concept.
In your view, in the controller GET method, fill the value for the date.
In the corresponding POST, you'll get this value or some other filled by the user. So, if it's a post, you'll never pass for the line of code filling the date for the first time.

Comment: can you explain more detailed?